# Nest js TypeOrmModule Unable to connect to the database e2e testing with docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to connect to postgres db specifically for e2e testing and I'm failing.
Relevant files:
app.e2e-spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppModule } from '../src/app.module';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { configValidationSchema } from '../src/config.schema';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { EventEntity } from '../src/event/event.entity';

describe('NestJS App E2E Tests', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          envFilePath: [`.env.stage.${process.env.STAGE}`],
          validationSchema: configValidationSchema,
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          imports: [ConfigModule],
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
            type: 'postgres',
            host:  configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
            port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
            username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
            password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
            database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
            entities: [EventEntity]
          }),
        })
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Hello!');
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

Dockerfile.test

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "test:e2e"]
```

docker-compose.e2e.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    test:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
            context: .
        environment: 
            NODE_ENV: test
            PORT: 3000
        depends_on: 
            - postgres
    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.4
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: db
            DATABASE_HOST: postgres
            POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
```

I assumed it's problem with configuration as I see this but nothing seem to help

2023-11-04 17:52:14.521 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
scheduler-postgres-1  | 2023-11-04 17:52:14.521 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
scheduler-postgres-1  | 2023-11-04 17:52:14.524 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
scheduler-postgres-1  | 2023-11-04 17:52:14.534 UTC [69] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-04 17:52:14 UTC
scheduler-postgres-1  | 2023-11-04 17:52:14.538 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

Comment: Do you need to also set the environment variables like `DATABASE_HOST` on the `test` container?  Is there an error that container writes out at startup (your logs only show output from the database container)?

Comment: shouldn't I set variables? I'm quite new to docker tbh
I see this error and exceeding timout with any value does not help

thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 10000 ms for a hook.
scheduler-test-1      |     Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
 6 |   let app: INestApplication;
  >  8 |   beforeEach(async () => {

Comment: Right now the useful `environment:` variables are only set for the `postgres` container, and you need to duplicate then in `test` as well.